# CMAKE - Add library don't work last turn of foreach

Tags: cmake, logic

I have a **CMakelist.txt** :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test)

set(TEST_HOME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

message("test SDK home directory: " ${TEST_HOME})

set(a true)
list(APPEND plugins a)
set(b true)
list(APPEND plugins b)
set(c true)
list(APPEND plugins c)
add_executable(test main.c)

foreach(plugin IN LISTS plugins)
  if(${${plugin}})
    file(GLOB ${plugin}-SRC "${TEST_HOME}/plugins/${plugin}/src/*.c")
    message(${${plugin}-SRC})
    add_library(slt_${plugin} SHARED ${${plugin}-SRC})
    message(${plugin})
    target_link_libraries(test slt_${plugin}.so)
  endif()
endforeach()
```

TLDR: I turn for create libraries and link them to my executable.

But my last library isn't created, the output of my **Makefile** generate by this **CMakelist.txt** is :

```
Scanning dependencies of target slt_c
[ 12%] Building C object CMakeFiles/slt_c.dir/plugins/c/src/c.c.o
[ 25%] Linking C shared library libslt_c.so
[ 25%] Built target slt_c
Scanning dependencies of target slt_b
[ 37%] Building C object CMakeFiles/slt_b.dir/plugins/b/src/b.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C shared library libslt_b.so
[ 50%] Built target slt_b
[ 62%] Linking C executable minko
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lslt_a
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lslt_b
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lslt_c
```

And when I turn **a** to **false**. It's be who don't build.
I really don't know what cause this, I just start CMAKE with some tests. Thank you.

Comment: Will you have so many plugins that looping is important? The instructions might be simpler to read, too, when you specify these shared libraries manually.

Comment: If you create a library in the project, link with it using **target**'s name: `target_link_libraries(test slt_${plugin})`, not a library file name. When you use target name, CMake not only automatically adjusts linker flags, but also creates a **dependency**, so linking will be performed only after the library is built.